# Editing discord role permissions. (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to write a command that will let a user create a role. So far I've gotten this:

```
if (msg.content == '-create')
{
    msg.guild.createRole({name:"new role", color: "00FFFF", mentionable: false});
}
```

I am trying to have it so it gives the role the admin perm. This is of course assuming that the bot also has admin perm.

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to create a role with an admin perm, I suggest you consult the [discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org).

When you go to create a role, a [RoleData object](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/RoleData) is required. You already have that, but you will need to add in an array with the permissions you want with the key `permissions`.

In that array all the permissions for the role must be listed. A list of all the permission flags is [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS).

So, for example if I wanted to create a role with the ability to mention everyone (assuming people are not given that permission by default), I would use:

`<Message>.guild.createRole( {name:"Mentioners", color: "#ff0000", permissions:["MENTION_EVERYONE"] } );`

I hope this helped you with your problem!

- Trifex

Comment: Thank you, for the answer. Figured it out literally after posting the question, still gonna leave it up for anyone else who may need it :)